# How can I remove a stone fireplace that is attached to drywall?

Tags: drywall, fireplace, demolition

I wish to remove a fireplace and the mantle above it. Can I just pry it off portions at a time or is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's attached to the drywall, rather than (as is almost certainly the case if this is a real fireplace and chimney) the drywall and supporting framing being attached around it? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh!Good to know about the drywall's position. We want to redo the floor and eventually the fireplace, but for now, I was just going to remove the fireplace and seal up any openings with drywall

Comment: That looks like a gas insert - can you post a picture from the side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those stones are just facing and can be knocked out with chisel/hammer combo.  The shelf might need a sledge hammer or a lot of whacks with hammer.

Comment: This is probably true, however you'll want to make sure before you start hammering away. Try prying one off, if it pops off then it's facing, if not then it may be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @GdD - I was assuming based on the insert and that the stone wasn't running all the way up.  Never have seen a real stone fire place cut off the stone on the inside a few feet up.